# Djoser Connection Error

Tags: python, django

I've been having some problems getting the Djoser password reset module to work on an API I'm developing for.

In my DJANGO Settings:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
EMAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
EMAIL_HOST_USER=<my_username@gmail.com>
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=<my_password>
EMAIL_PORT=587
```

For my Djoser settings:

```
 DJOSER = {
        'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': '#/password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    }
```

Call stack:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/auth/password/reset/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/metpetdb/.virtualenvs/api/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/metpetdb/.virtualenvs/api/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/metpetdb/.virtualenvs/api/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/metpetdb/.virtualenvs/api/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/metpetdb/.virtualenvs/api/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/metpetdb/.virtualenvs/api/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 463, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "vendor/djoser/djoser/utils.py", line 57, in post
    return self.action(serializer)
  File "vendor/djoser/djoser/views.py", line 116, in action
    self.send_email(**self.get_send_email_kwargs(user))
  File "vendor/djoser/djoser/utils.py", line 72, in send_email
    send_email(to_email, from_email, context, **self.get_send_email_extras())
  File "vendor/djoser/djoser/utils.py", line 49, in send_email
    email_message.send()
  File "/home/metpetdb/.virtualenvs/api/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 292, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/metpetdb/.virtualenvs/api/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/home/metpetdb/.virtualenvs/api/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 58, in open
    self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 242, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 321, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 292, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 512, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 503, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
Internal Server Error: /api/auth/password/reset/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/metpetdb/.virtualenvs/api/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/metpetdb/.virtualenvs/api/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/metpetdb/.virtualenvs/api/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/metpetdb/.virtualenvs/api/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/metpetdb/.virtualenvs/api/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/metpetdb/.virtualenvs/api/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 463, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "vendor/djoser/djoser/utils.py", line 57, in post
    return self.action(serializer)
  File "vendor/djoser/djoser/views.py", line 116, in action
    self.send_email(**self.get_send_email_kwargs(user))
  File "vendor/djoser/djoser/utils.py", line 72, in send_email
    send_email(to_email, from_email, context, **self.get_send_email_extras())
  File "vendor/djoser/djoser/utils.py", line 49, in send_email
    email_message.send()
  File "/home/metpetdb/.virtualenvs/api/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 292, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/metpetdb/.virtualenvs/api/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/home/metpetdb/.virtualenvs/api/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 58, in open
    self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 242, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 321, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 292, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 512, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 503, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I'm new to using the Djoser module and I've spent too many hours trying to figure out the cause of the connection error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that you need to include the full DJOSER settings?

```
 DJOSER = {
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': '#/password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': '#/activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {},
 }
```

Also, I made the mistake of not putting my email configuration in quotes, i.e. EMAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com instead of EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'